# Having issues with Handler in Android

Tags: java, android, handler

I am creating a `Handler` but for some reason the `if statement` does not `trigger`. The Log is printing out the correct value right before the `if statement`.

```
mHandler = new Handler() { 
@Override public void handleMessage(Message msg) { 
    String s=(String)msg.obj;
    s = s.trim();
    Log.v("mHandler reply", s);
    if(s == "OK"){
       Dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

};

Here is the log

```
03-24 09:02:53.707: V/mHandler reply(7331): OK
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: Use `equals()` for testing string equality.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `equals()` method instead of `==` operator for `String` comparison as follows...

```
if(s.equals("OK")){
   Dialog.dismiss();
}
```

To get more information check [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)